# Preprocessor #if Array

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I'm working with a huge code and want to do a little calculation in a parameters file, therefore I'm using preprocessor language.

So

```
const D_REAL spher2car[3] = { 
    sin(theta)*cos(phi),  
    sin(theta)*sin(phi),
    cos(theta)
}; 

const D_REAL spher2car2[3] = { 
    spher2car[0]+h0*sin(thetap)*cos(phip),
    spher2car[1]+h0*sin(thetap)*sin(phip),
    spher2car[2]+h0*cos(thetap)
}; 

#if (spher2car[2]<spher2car2[2])
```

Gives me the error

```
 the token "[" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

So basically I have to set a value that will not change anymore, but is dependend of other constant parameters before the program starts.

How would I do that?

Comment: You *do* know that the preprocessor is a compile-time only thing (it will even run before the actual parser runs)? And doesn't know anything about variables or their run-time values?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe there is a misconception here about `const` not being variable.

Comment: But apparently even just the first two lines alone are not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor runs even before the compiler.  What you have can only be evaluated at run time.  So use a regular `if` statement instead:

```
if (spher2car[2]<spher2car2[2]) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Note that because this is executable code that is **must** reside inside of a function.  The same goes for the variable declarations above, as expressions must be evaluated to initialize them.

A good place to do this is in `main` before you do anything else.